# FabricJS div over object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

I use FabricJS with kitchensink app to add images on a canvas on client side. But I want to display a div when the object is selected.
What I have done : I display a div when a object is selected.
What I want to do : display these div at the center of the object and keep it at this point when object is mooving.

How can I do that ? I am trying to edit CSS position with moving event but can't find how to put it at the center of the object. Maybe it's not the good solution

Thanks for help

Edit my code now :

```
    canvas.on('object:moving', modifiedHandler);

function modifiedHandler(evt) {
  var obj=evt.target;
  var left= obj.left + this._offset.left;
  var top = obj.top + this._offset.top;
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn-image-edit');
  $("#btn-image-edit").css({top:(top-btn.offsetHeight)/2, left: (left-btn.offsetWidth)/2, position:'absolute'});
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this, [Interaction with objects outside canvas](http://fabricjs.com/interaction-with-objects-outside-canvas).  Fairly close, no?

Comment: Yes I try to use it but I have difficulties when you rotate the element its cause troubles. I How can I get the center of the object to set it in css top and left ?